# How can I change the start date of the year in snowflake?

Tags: date, time, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I make it so that I can use all of the handy snowflake functions like year() dayofyear() quarter() but have it start on a different day?
Eg.
I want the desired start date not on Jan 1st but on Oct 1st of that year

Comment: why you tagged postgresql?

Comment: How is this related with `sf`?

Comment: Are you asking how to subtract a number of months from a date?